# В чём причина некорректной работы скрипта?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть селект и форма input text. Нужно, чтобы набрав текст в форме сделать неактивным селект и наоборот, т.е. одно из двух.

```js
function checkParams() {
  var time = $('#time').val();

  if (time.length == 0) {
    $('#time_of_day').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#time_of_day').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }

  $("#time_of_day").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Утром' || $(this).val() == 'Днём' || $(this).val() == 'Вечером' || $(this).val() == 'Ночью') {
      $('#time').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $('#time').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="time_of_day" id="time_of_day" onkeyup='checkParams()'>
  <option value="default" selected>...</option>
  <option value="Утром">Утром</option>
  <option value="Днём">Днём</option>
  <option value="Вечером">Вечером</option>
  <option value="Ночью">Ночью</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control floating-label" onkeyup='checkParams()'>
```

Скрипт работает мягко сказать рандомно, JS только начал осваивать, прошу хотя бы просто указать на ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас был неправильно расположен `$("#time_of_day").on('change', function() {`,
его следовало расположить вне функции-обработчика `checkParams()`.
Также исправил условие для `if`.
И желательно использовать метод `onchange()` для `select'а`.

```js
//Обработчик вне функции
$("#time_of_day").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() != 'default') {          //Обратите внимание на условие
    $('#time').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('#time').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});

function checkParams() {
  var time = $('#time').val();

  if (time.length == 0) {
    $('#time_of_day').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('#time_of_day').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="time_of_day" id="time_of_day" onchange='checkParams()'>
  <option value="default" selected>...</option>
  <option value="Утром">Утром</option>
  <option value="Днём">Днём</option>
  <option value="Вечером">Вечером</option>
  <option value="Ночью">Ночью</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control floating-label" onkeyup='checkParams()'>
```